# Javascript function to display items in an array as a vertical list?

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a little website that allows the user to earn achievements based off a specific number of accomplishments. And I'm looking for a clean way to print the earned accomplishments on the screen from an Array.

Basically I want a vertical list display of an array that can update based on user interaction.

currently I have this:

```
function win() {
check = Number(localStorage.snum);

switch(check) {

    case 50:
    prizes.unshift('50: You infant');
    localStorage.priz = prizes;
    document.getElementById('awards').innerHTML = prizes;
    break;

    case 100:
    prizes.unshift('100: big whoop');
    localStorage.priz = prizes;
    document.getElementById('awards').innerHTML = prizes;
    break; 
}
}
```

and in the html I have

```
<div id="numbox"> </div>
<div id="awards"></div>
```

Amongst other things.

I would ideally like an 'Achievement box" that displays the array as a vertical list.

Help?

EDIT: I took out `<br />` That I had in there as a hackjob vertical list.

I guess an Array would look like `var prizes= new Array('50: You infant', '100: big whoop');`

Comment: Could you post a sample array for us to see what you're working with?

Comment: It seems you want an unordered list (`<ul>`)?

Comment: The array starts out empty and as user increases counter things are added to the beginning of it.

`prizes = new Array();`

`<ul>` would be great.

Comment: I just noticed, having voted up [@Felix's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808525/javascript-function-to-display-items-in-an-array-as-a-vertical-list/5808727#5808727). Previous comment deleted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start:

```
var awards = {
    50: 'You infant',
    100: 'big whoop'
};

function win() {
    var points = +localStorage.snum; // shortcut to convert to a number
    if(points in awards) {
        var prize = awards[points];
        prizes.unshift(prize);
        localStorage.priz = prizes; // not sure if you really need this

        var list = document.getElementById('awards');
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = points + ': ' + prize;
        list.insertBefore(li, list.firstChild); // inserting at the beginning
    }
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<ul id="awards"></ul>
```

Using this kind of map makes it easier to extend it later ( I don't think you want to write a thousand `case` statements ;)).

You can style the list however you want to with CSS.

**Update:** [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/RBxTa/), [**another DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/RBxTa/2/)

Comment: This displays the entire array right away? Can I add items to the array to be displayed only when a certain number is reached? Also, the list shows up with an obscure comma?

Comment: @Talon: I'm not really sure what you mean. I don't know when you call `win` or how you set the points for a user. The code is nearly doing the same as yours but it's structure is different. `awards` is just used instead of the `switch` statement. Here is a DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/RBxTa/

Comment: Okay, I think that will work. I just need to know how, instead of having a dedicated button, I can have the code check every time to see if document.getElementById('numbox').innerHTML = the value of localStorage.snum; and if so print the specific achievement associated with that value.

Comment: @Talon: I added another demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/RBxTa/2/ as I said I don't know how you compute the points or whatever. The button is just for the demo.

Comment: One more question. How can I save the achievements so that the next time the user visits they load up?

Comment: Using `localStorage` should be fine (but only works in newer browsers). Just check on page load if `localStorage.priz` is set, iterate over it and build the list.

Comment: How do I rebuild the list? Sorry, I'm all noob.

Comment: @Talon: You can do it similar as shown above. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3Ja6T/ Btw. it is better to just store the point values a user reached, not the text (as we do above). This saves space and you can easily change the text later.

Comment: @Felix Kling: That would work but I can't seem to save the Array in localStorage as an array. catch my drift?

Comment: @Talon: I think you have to serialize and unserialize the array. Use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` for that. All browsers that support `localStorage` should also support `JSON`.

Comment: Got it all figured out and it works across all the newest browser versions. Except I don't know about IE9. But if you're interested I posted the project here. http://talon.99k.org/higher.html